# Android Room - Inserting works but select doesn´t return any values

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i want to select data from a database via room.

Here are my code.

**Database**

```
@Database(entities = [TicketDb::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(DatabaseConverters::class)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun ticketDbDao(): TicketDbDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): MyDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MyDatabase::class.java,
                    "my_database"
                )
        .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "ticket_table")
data class TicketDb (@ColumnInfo(name = "ticketnumber")  var ticketnumber: String = "1234567") {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0
}
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface TicketDbDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(ticket: TicketDb)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ticket_table ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAllTickets(): LiveData<List<TicketDb>>
}
```

**Repository**

```
class TicketRepository (private val ticketDbDao: TicketDbDao) {

    val allTickets: LiveData<List<TicketDb>> = ticketDbDao.getAllTickets()

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(ticket: TicketDb) {
        ticketDbDao.insert(ticket)
    }

}
```

**Viewmodel**

```
var ticketRepository: TicketRepository

val allTickets: LiveData<List<TicketDb>>

init {
    val ticketDao = MeinLottoDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).ticketDbDao()
    ticketRepository = TicketRepository(ticketDao)
    allTickets = ticketRepository.allTickets
}

fun saveTicket() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ticketRepository.insert(ticket.value!!.toTicketDb())
}
```

The saveTicket method works. I have downloaded the database and all saved entries are present.
But whenever I call ticketRepository.allTickets I get an empty list back.

I have set a breakpoint in the auto generated class TicketDbDao_Impl in the call-method in the Callable object, but the breakpoint is never reached.

```
@Override
  public LiveData<List<TicketDb>> getAllTickets() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM ticket_table";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    return __db.getInvalidationTracker().createLiveData(new String[]{"ticket_table"}, false, new Callable<List<TicketDb>>() {
      @Override
      public List<TicketDb> call() throws Exception {
        final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false);
        try {
          // BREAKPOINT here
          final int _cursorIndexOfId = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "id");
          final int _cursorIndexOfName = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "name");
```

Comment: First try with simple getall "SELECT * FROM ticket_table" without live data.If it is working then let me know.

Comment: Hi, i habe tried to select a list without livedata. But the list is also empty.

Comment: with simple quesry ""SELECT * FROM ticket_table"" also you are getting empty ?

Comment: Hi, i tried this and it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried same code with few changes, working fine with me

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val ticket1 = TicketDb("1")
        val ticket2 = TicketDb("12")
        val ticket3 = TicketDb("1123")
        val ticket4 = TicketDb("4214")

        MyDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).ticketDbDao()?.run {
            insert(ticket1)
            insert(ticket2)
            insert(ticket3)
            insert(ticket4)
        }

        val data = MyDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).ticketDbDao().getAllTickets()

        Log.i("Hardik", "Data :$data")

    }
}
```

**MyDatabase**

```
@Database(entities = [TicketDb::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun ticketDbDao(): TicketDbDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): MyDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    MyDatabase::class.java,
                    "my_database"
                ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TicketDb**

```
@Entity(tableName = "ticket_table")
data class TicketDb(@ColumnInfo(name = "ticketnumber") var ticketnumber: String = "1234567") {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

**TicketDbDao**
@Dao
interface TicketDbDao {

```
@Insert
fun insert(ticket: TicketDb)

@Query("SELECT * FROM ticket_table ORDER BY id DESC")
fun getAllTickets(): List<TicketDb>
```

}

this give me inserted data in log as below

```
2019-07-12 15:48:51.179 30262-30262/com.hardik.demos I/Hardik: Data :[TicketDb(ticketnumber=4214), TicketDb(ticketnumber=1123), TicketDb(ticketnumber=12), TicketDb(ticketnumber=1), TicketDb(ticketnumber=4214), TicketDb(ticketnumber=1123), TicketDb(ticketnumber=12), TicketDb(ticketnumber=1), TicketDb(ticketnumber=1), TicketDb(ticketnumber=1), TicketDb(ticketnumber=1)]
```

Comment: Hi, i have used your example, that works, to adapt my code.
Now it´s working. Seems that LiveData doesn´t work as expected.

Comment: It would be great to add some notice what was changed...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem while retrieving data from the room. The following code is not tested, but to guide you I am trying to solve. Check and reply in comment if it works or not.

```
@Dao
interface TicketDbDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(ticket: TicketDb)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ticket_table ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAllTickets(): LiveData<List<TicketDb>>
}
```

I think room query returns list data, but you are trying to get livedata object. So change to following code for **dao** operation.

```
@Dao
interface TicketDbDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(ticket: TicketDb)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ticket_table ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getAllTickets(): List<TicketDb>
}
```

**TicketRepository**

```
class TicketRepository (private val ticketDbDao: TicketDbDao) {

    val allTickets: List<TicketDb> 
        get() = ticketDbDao.getAllTickets()

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(ticket: TicketDb) {
        ticketDbDao.insert(ticket)
    }
}
```

Now in your **viewmodel**

```
var ticketRepository: TicketRepository

private val _allTickets = MutableLiveData<List<TicketDb>>() // backing property should be used for updating values

val allTickets: LiveData<List<TicketDb>> = _allTickets // mutable live data should not be exposed

init {
    val ticketDao = MeinLottoDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).ticketDbDao()
    ticketRepository = TicketRepository(ticketDao)

}

fun getTicketValues(){
    _allTickets.value = ticketRepository.allTickets
}

fun saveTicket() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        ticketRepository.insert(ticket.value!!.toTicketDb())
}
```

Comment: I am working with this tutorial, where livedata is the correct type. 

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5

I´ve tried to change to List instead of LiveData, but the returned list ist also empty.

Answer (score 1):

You must observe the livedata in your activity or fragment，such as

```
 ViewModel.allTickets.observe(this, new Observer<>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
          
        }
    });
```